# Generated bootstrap navbar not applying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have generated an navbar colors for my website through:

http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0

I have copied LESS code and input that into my less file and compiles it into style.css. As you can see below my style.css is below bootstrap however colors do not apply to my navbar. Anyone had similar problem and know how to fix it?

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../build/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Is a file found by the path `../build/css/style.css`? Did you check it with code inspector?

Comment: Yes it is found as any other code from that file is working

Comment: Could you give a link to your website?

Comment: Yeah sure, https://selene.hud.ac.uk/u1358595/assign/app/home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because on your website you use `navbar-inverse` class instead of `navbar-default`.